# SpringBoot: how to enable a @Configuration Class only if the corresponding @EnablerAnnotation has been used on a class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, configuration

How can I enable a `@Configuration` class only if the corresponding `@EnableCustomConfiguration` annotation has been used?

To make it clear I am trying to recreate the behaviour of common SpringBoot annotations, like e.g. `@EnableEurekaClient`, `@EnableWebSecurity` and so on.

This is my enabler:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EnableMultitenancy {}
```

Here my configuration properties:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("multitenancy")
public class MultitenancyProperties {
    @NotEmpty(message = "You must provide at least one tenant")
    private List<Tenant> tenants;
}
```

and this is my Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@Conditional("On EnableMultitenancy used")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultitenancyProperties.class)
public class MultitenancyConfiguration{
    @Bean
    public MyFirstBean first(MultitenancyProperties properties){
        return new MyFirstBean(properties);
    }

    @Bean
    public MySecondBean second(MultitenancyProperties properties){
        return new MySecondBean(properties);
    }
}
```

How can I write such a condition, e.g. the annotation has been used on a class/component?

Answer (score 0):

`org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionContext` interface shows theability of `@Conditional`.

ConditionContext contains five methods:

- getRegistry
- getBeanFactory
- getEnvironment
- getResourceLoader
- getClassLoader

So it seems your cannot directly depend on annotation, eg: `@EnableCaching`. But you can depend on the bean related to them, eg: ProxyCachingConfiguration for `EnableCaching`.

But i think is not a good design. Usually we will **declare** our dependency, this makes component sperately, also make things easy. When user want to use our component, they don't need to add all of depended annotation, eg: `@EnableEureka`,`@EnableWebSecurity`, just `@ MultitenancyConfiguration`.

Answer (score -1):

In your `MultitenancyConfiguration` class, you just need to replace the current `@Conditional` annotation with `@ConditionalOnClass(EnableMulitenancy.class)`.

Update: Sorry, I misunderstood. Why don't you just import the `MultitenancyConfiguration` class by using `@Import(MultitenancyConfiguration.class)` in your `EnableMultitenancy` class? This will guarantee that your `MultitenancyConfiguration` class is enabled whenever `@EnableMultitenancy` is used.

Comment: This is not correct. It checks only if it is on the Class Path, not if it is used or not.

Comment: @1Z10 You are right, I misunderstood. Updated my answer.